# django static files loading error in aws-s3 buscket

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

here is my aws conf file:

```
import datetime

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''

AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'monetimes.aws.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'monetimes.aws.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'monetimes-static-bucket'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'ap-south-1'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

two_months = datetime.timedelta(days=61)
date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + two_months
expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT")

AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d' % (int(two_months.total_seconds()), ),
}

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True
```

[image]

I am putting my static files to aws-s3 buket by making it full access and in public mode.

static files are coming and copying to my aws-s3 bucket but showing some errors.

please check the above screen-shot for the error.

I am adding key and secret key properly also

[image]

by default in my s3 bucket it is coming asia-mumbai location.

and i am procedding with the same

Comment: Can you tell us what versions of boto and storages you are using?  As a quick fix, try setting `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION='s3v4'`.

Comment: boto3==1.9.71
botocore==1.12.71
Django==2.1.4
django-storages==1.7.1

Comment: @soubhagya : were you able to make it work. I'm having similar problem where ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput is returning boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request . The error comes only when bucket is in ap-south-1 . It works if I have s3 bucket in us-west-2. I tried AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION='s3v4' as suggested by Akber but same error.

Comment: FYI: For me following two settings worked: S3_USE_SIGV4 = True and
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.' + AWS_REGION + '.amazonaws.com'